# Docky has problems with zoom

Tags: fedora

I just install docky on fedora 20.
the problems is i can't enable feature zoom on docky.
I was trying with gconf-editor,i click option zoom docky on gnome do,but notification appear that "This key has no schema.
I also install compiz manager but i don't where.I can't solve this problem abot docky
thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=595154

It's not a problem so much as this function is not supported in Fedora